# Performance issue using Row Level Security using lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-level-security

I have implemented Row Level Security using on SQL Server 2016. I think I have a failry complex setup, but our security requirement is complex.

This is in the context of a data warehouse. I have basic fact and dimension tables. I applied row level security to one of my dimension table with the following setup:

> **Table 1** : dimDataSources (standard physical table)
>   **Table 2** : dimDataSources_Secured (Memory Optimized table)

I created a Security Policy on the `dimDataSources_Secured` (In-Memory) that uses a Natively Compiled function. That function read another Memory Optimized table that contains lookup values and Active Directory Groups that can read the record.
The function use the `is_member()` function to return 1 for all records that are allowed for my groups.

So the context seems a bit complex but so far it works.
But... now I get to use this in jonctions with fact table and we get performance hit. Here, I am not applying row level security directly on the fact table... only on the dimension table.

So my problem is if I run this:

```
SELECT SUM(Sales) FROM factSales
```

It returns quickly, let's say 2 seconds.

If I run the same query but with a join on the secured table (or view), it will take 5-6 times longer:

```
SELECT SUM(Sales) FROM factSales f
INNER JOIN dimDataSources_Secured d ON f.DataSourceKey = d.DataSourceKey
```

This retrieves only the source I have access to based on my AD groups.
When the execution plan changes, it seems like it retrieves the fact table data quickly, but then will do a nested loop lookup on the In-Memory table to get the allowed records.

Is that behavior caused by the usage of the Filter Predicate functions?
Anyone had good or bad experiences using Row Level Security?
Is it mature enough to put in production?
Is it a good candidate for data warehousing (i.e. processing big volumes of data)?

It is hard to put more details on my actual function and queries without writing a novel. I'm mostly looking for guidelines or alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that behavior caused by the usage of the Filter Predicate
>   functions? Anyone had good or bad experiences using Row Level
>   Security? is it mature enough to put in production? Is it a good
>   candidate for datawarhousing (processing of big volume of Data)?

Yea, you'll take a performance hit when using RLS. Aaron Bertrand wrote a good [piece](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4778/performance-impact-of-sql-server-2016-rowlevel-security/) in March of 2017 on it. [Ben Snaidero](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4194/test-performance-overhead-of-sql-server-row-level-security/) wrote a good one in 2016. Microsoft has also provided [guidance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/04/23/row-level-security-performance-and-common-patterns/) on patterns to limit performance impact.

I've never seen RLS implemented for a OLAP schema so I can't comment on that. Without seeing your filter predicates, it's tough to say, but that's usually where the devil is.

Comment: And complex security requirements don't require expensive RLS lookups.  You can almost always calculate the entitlements for each user ahead of time to simplify the runtime cost of evaluating the RLS.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Do you mean for OLAP or OLTP as well, and how to account for temporal rights without RLS i.e. Bob is allowed until November 2018?

Comment: I see RLS mostly for reporting, but sometimes against an OLTP schema.  For temporal rights, I usually re-calculate and store the data entitlements nightly.  Keeping the runtime query processing to apply RLS to a minimum.  YMMV and you may have the resources to calculate complicated rules at runtime, especially if it's as simple as `and rls.EndDate < getdate()`, but you'd have to test.